# Filter user by role on select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have user with role : admin, manager, cashier. User model relation with Employee model.

Employee belongs_to User and
User has_many Employee

In new form employee, i used this method

```
<%= form_for @employee, remote: true, html: {role: "form", multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :user_id, 'User', class: "exampleInputEmail1" %>
    <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@users.map {|u|[u.name, u.id]}, f.object.user_id), {prompt: "Select User"}, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

Using a method above, i get all of user. But i want to filter only user with role "admin" on the select. How to get that?

**Edit**

employees_controller

new and create action

```
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save
        format.html { redirect_to employees_path, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @employee }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Edit 2**

Forget to add this. Relation user and role.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles
end
```

**Edit 3**

schema.rb

```
  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "user_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "user_roles", ["role_id"], name: "index_user_roles_on_role_id", using: :btree
  add_index "user_roles", ["user_id"], name: "index_user_roles_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "auth_token"
    t.string   "password_reset_token"
    t.datetime "password_reset_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "user_roles", "roles"
  add_foreign_key "user_roles", "users"

  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "employee_code"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "age"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "telp"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"   
  end
```

Comment: Since, if my understanding is correct, you are always only going to want  admin users in this form  I would recommend filtering that in the controller and then the variable you are using (@users.map)  will only contain those admin users, can you post your employee controller?

Comment: Ok. I have posted employee controller

Comment: where are you defining `@users`?

Comment: Ups sorry, edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit.

You can pull through the admins by using:

```
@user.roles.where(name: 'Admin')
```

This assumes your Role class has stored the role in a column called "Name" and that the name given to the Admin is "Admin" - if not then replace the inside of the brackets with (your_role_column: 'Your Admin name').

Comment: I have edited my code for user and role. I tried to use your method, this the error ERROR:  column users.role does not exist

Comment: I've edited the query above - you can try something similar to that. My original code won't work because you didn't use an enum to define the roles, but a join table. You might want to define @users in your Controller using my query, then just pass through that collection to the options_for_select method.

Comment: The code itself will depend on whether you have named the column including the role "role" or something else. It might help if you share the migration for the Role table.

Comment: My Role table only have 'name' attribute. I used 'attr_accessor :selected_role' something like 'role_ids' in my user model for select name of role.

Comment: I've updated the query then. Basically the first part of the () is your column_name: (given your answer I believe it to be 'name:') and the second part is whatever you called an admin (most likely 'Admin' but change it if you've called it something else).

Comment: Sorry sir, i stiil newbie in rails. i tried to change @users = User.all in my controller with @user.roles.where(name: 'admin'), isn't right?

Comment: Can you post the content of your schema.rb file (specifically the content for your Role class) please?

Comment: I have added my schema.rb

Comment: You can play around with the methods in the source code here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html - otherwise why not just set a new column on the User model called admin and make it a boolean. Then do an after_save and after_update method that sets admin: :true if the user_role is set to admin

Comment: I tried add status to user and it's work !! Thank's :)

Comment: I used your method too :)

Answer (score 0):

better way is to use scopes:

in model:

```
scope :admins, ->{ where(name: 'Admin') }
```

in controller:

```
User.admins
```